# val child: ImageView = gridLayout.getChildAt(i) as ImageView crashes my app

Tags: android, kotlin

When i run my app it crash with this phrase ( sorry for bad English )

I tried a lot to resolve this problem but i cant

[image]

Comment: Need just a little bit more code.

Answer (score 1):

`gridLayout.getChildAt` return null as the message says.

Try changing your condition with `gridLayout.getchildCount()-1`

Answer (score 0):

You are looping until the gridlayout childCount and array indices start at 0 in kotlin.

So if you have an array of 10 elements, to access the first element you index it like array[0], for the second element you use array[1] and so on. So if you try to access array[10] that means you are trying to get the 11th element which doesn't exist as your array has a total of 10 elements. The last element in this example array is at index 9 so you access it by calling array[9].

In your case by looping until gridLayout.getChildCount(), when the loop reaches the last element it will try to access an element that doesn't exist in the array.
So you should loop until gridLayout.getChildCount() - 1 because that's the correct index for the last element.